# AWS sdk for C#, where to put the App.config file?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have a C# console application that uploads files to s3 storage.

It works fine when I debug it from inside Visual Studio, however, when I build the .exe and run it off my server, I get errors saying that it couldn't find the Access Key inside the App.config file.

```
System.ArgumentException: Access Key could not be found.  Add an appsetting to your App.config with the name AWSAccessKey with a value of your access key.
```

And also:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to reach credentials server
```

The second error is might be  caused by the first.

I have my App.config file in the same directory as the .exe I'm running, but that doesn't help.

What else do I have to do?

Here's my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="key"/>
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="secret"/>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2" />
  </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The build action for this file is "Embedded Resource" I've also tried changing it to "Content" and that didn't help.

---

Some things that may or may not be relevant:

I'm using `ILMerge` to merge the `AWSSDK.dll` (among others) into the `exe`, then I run that file off of an Amazon EC2 instance through the command line.

Comment: Just some basic housekeeping... your config file is named as your_app_name.exe.config and does have a proper structure with an appsettings node in the xml?

Comment: @Doug It's just named "App.config", and it's filled out correctly. I'll change the name and see if that works... Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: When you look in your "bin" directory, the .config file should be named yourprogram.exe.config. It won't find the configuration values otherwise, and it should be a content file, not an embedded resource. The .config file must always be present and in the same directory as the EXE.

Comment: @vcsjones That worked. I renamed the file when I merged it with the .dlls, so what I had to do was to take that file, move it, and also rename it so that it matched. If you want to make that commend an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look in your "bin" directory, the .config file should be named yourprogram.exe.config. It won't find the configuration values otherwise, and it should be a content file, not an embedded resource. The .config file must always be present and in the same directory as the EXE.

Answer (score 3):

Something to consider, either for this particular problem or going forward, if you create an IAM role, assign it a set of permissions and then launch your EC2 instances with that IAM role the access keys will automatically be made available to the SDK and you won't have to risk storing them in a config file like you are doing now.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html